# Getting lots of traffic from russia to an unpublished site

Tags: security, spam, traffic

I am currently building a website. Currently nobody knows about it but it is already reachable for testing purposes. Now I saw, that I get a lot of traffic from russia (Its a german website hosted on google app engine).

The traffic is pretty constant every day. I tried to figure out the sources but the domains are not registered or I can't figure what the sites about because I do not speak russian.

Attached find a screenshot showing the channels from google analytics.

What could this be? Hackers? Bots? Should I be worried about that? Should I take action to prevent that traffic?

[image]

Comment: Not that this helps you, but I"m having the same exact occurrence happen to me. I saw in Google Analytics that my website (that is only 2 weeks old) has 40% of it's traffic coming from Russia. And they are using Linux systems. Very curious indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, yeah, They [TM] find you.  [Here's a live map of current attacks.](http://map.ipviking.com/)

I wouldn't be too concerned unless they seem to be performing successful attacks.  Unfortunately, this is just... being on the Internet.